# Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: invalid argument (vagrant)

Tags: go-ethereum, dapp-development, nodes

I'm trying to set up a local node in Vagrant (trusty64, geth 1.7.1-stable):

```
geth --identity "test_remote" --datadir "./geth_data_remote" --trace "./geth_data_remote/trace.txt" --dev
```

and getting the following error:

> 19:00:20.199679 syncDir: sync /var/www/vhosts/localhost/htdocs/geth_data_remote/geth/chaindata: invalid argument
>   19:00:20.199749 CURRENT: sync /var/www/vhosts/localhost/htdocs/geth_data_remote/geth/chaindata: invalid argument

Locally (OSX 10.12.6, geth 1.6.7-stable) it works very well that's why I can't get the problem. Does anybody have a clue?

p.s. it also works, if I don't specify the directory, but it's still quite important for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using vagrant, it seems you are trying to set datachain on shared folder, which is on your system and it's not correctly formatted.

Change **--datadir ./geth_data_remote** to **--datadir ~/geth_data_remote** and it will work.